# Redirection into blank page laravel 5.4

Tags: redirect, laravel-5

I have a problem here in my **Laravel 5.4** project multi-auth system. The problem is Laravel redirects me to a blank page, let's say instead of admin/home it redirects me to a blank page has URI /admin
here is my migrations first is **admin**.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('adress');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('cin')->unique()->unsigned();
            $table->integer('phone')->unique()->unsigned();
            $table->string('sexe');
            $table->boolean('activation')->default(0);
            $table->string('token',254)->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

And here is the admin model implementation:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\notifications\AdminResetPasswordNotification;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new AdminResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name' , 'last_name' , 'adress', 'email' , 'password' , 'cin' , 'phone' , 'sexe', 'activation'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function roleUser(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\RoleUser');
    }

    public function salary(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Salary');
    }


    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Image','imageable');
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
    }   

}
```

Third here is roleuser migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRoleUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_users');
    }
}
```

RoleUser MODEL

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RoleUser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name' , 'admin_id'
    ];

    public function admin(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
    }
}
```

So I duplicate the auth folder views in admin folder in views and I changed actions.

```
@extends('layouts.subhome')

@section('content')
@include('includes.wow')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login sfdsgf</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('admin.password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
@endsection
```

Here is the login controller:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */

        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = 'admin/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
           //$this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
        }

        /**
         * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
        {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

            foreach ($this->guard()->user()->roleUser() as $role) {

                if ($role->name == 'Amministratore') {

                   return redirect('admin/home');

                }elseif($role->name == 'Avocate') {

                   return redirect('avocate/home');

                }elseif($role->name == 'Reddattore Professionale') {

                   return redirect('reddattoreprofessionale/home');

                }elseif($role->name == 'Reddattore Apprendista') {

                   return redirect('reddattoreapprendista/home');

                }elseif($role->name == 'Segretario') {

                   return redirect('segretario/home');

                }else{

                   return redirect('/');

                }

            }
        }


         /**
         * Show the application's login form.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function showLoginForm()
        {
            return view('admin.login');
        }

        /**
         * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
         */
        protected function guard()
        {
            return Auth::guard('admin');
        }

    }
```

This is the list of routes:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

Route::get('/subscribe', function () {
    return view('admSubscribe');
})->name('adminsub');

Route::GET('/sottoscrizione/lavoro', 'AdminController@index');

Route::RESOURCE('/sottoscrizione/lavoro', 'AdminController');

Auth::routes();

Route::GET('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::GET('admin/home','AdminController@showHome')->name('admin.home');

Route::GET('avocate/home','AvocatController@showHome')->name('avocat.home');

Route::GET('reddattoreprofessionale/home','ProfessionalRedactorController@showHome')->name('redpro.home');

Route::GET('reddattoreapprendista/home','TrainerRedactorController@showHome')->name('redtrain.home');

Route::GET('segretario/home','SecretaryController@showHome')->name('segretario.home');

Route::GET('admin','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login'); 

Route::POST('admin','Admin\LoginController@login');

Route::POST('admin-password/email','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email');

Route::GET('admin-password/reset','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.request'); 

Route::POST('admin-password/reset','Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset');

Route::GET('admin-password/reset/{token}','Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
```

Ok please help, I've been stuck here for 4 weeks in this problem.

Comment: Text reads itself easier with proper uppercase and lowercase. Please change your question accordingly.

Comment: Every single question and answer in the entire stack exchange network is written with proper capitalization, that is, in lowercase letters.  What makes you believe that you are so special as to write your question in uppercase, or that your question somehow needs to be written in uppercase?